# Triggering Sharepoint 2013 workflow when listitem version was changed

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-2013, workflow-foundation, sharepoint-workflow

I have a document library in share point 2013 foundation and  I need to trigger a workflow to send email to the administrator only when the  version of the listitem  of document  library was changed. I have a attached a workflow to the list item of document library when item was added and updated. I need to put a condition in the designer workflow  to check whether the version of the document is changed or not.  Can anyone help me on this please.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Any chance to do that with an Event Receiver ? The usage seems relevant.

Comment: I have tried the same in event Recevicer(Updated).  While updating the  file content and metadata the updated event is firing twice  as it will fire for file content and metadata  update  with same file version. we are getting  same file version  two times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, one thing you can do is to store the current version in an another  field, let's say we name it "Previous version".

When a change occured, you check if the version of the newest item is equal to your field "Previous version", if not, you know that the version have changed and :

- You send an email to the administrator
- Then you update your field "Previous version".

Seems pretty easy and works with Event Receiver or Workflow Designer.